# Math operations

Tags: javascript, calculator

I´m begginer programmer and its my first time writing here. So my goal is to make a robust calculator and right now i found myself facing a problem with changing operations in middle of my computing - for example: I got 1+1 but when I´m in 1+ and want to change it to a -,/ or * I cant. Tried to found a solution but others do their computation their own way so I´m asking here. Draft your question is advising to show minimum of a code so i post what i think is relevant bellow. If someone need more code to help me with this problem I can send a codepen link but its advised against to send it here.

```js
class Calculator {
    constructor(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement){
        this.previousOperandTextElement = previousOperandTextElement;
        this.currentOperandTextElement = currentOperandTextElement;
        this.readyToReset = false;
        this.clear();
    }

    clear() {
        this.currentOperand = "";
        this.previousOperand = "";
        this.operation = undefined;

    }

    delete() {
        this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString().slice(0, -1);
    }

    appendNumber(number) {
        if (number === "." && this.currentOperand.includes(".")) return
        this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString() + number.toString();
    }

    chooseOperation(operation) {
        if (this.currentOperand === "") return
        if (this.currentOperand !== "" && this.previousOperand !== "") this.compute();
        this.operation = operation;
        this.previousOperand = this.currentOperand;
        this.currentOperand = "";
    }

    compute() {
        let computation
        const prev = parseFloat(this.previousOperand);
        const current = parseFloat(this.currentOperand);
        if (isNaN(prev) || isNaN(current)) return;
        switch (this.operation)  {

        case "+":
            computation = prev + current;
        break;

        case "-":
            computation = prev - current;
        break;

        case "*":
            computation = prev * current;
        break;

        case "÷":
            computation = prev / current;
        break;
        default:
        return;
    
        }
        this.readyToReset = true;
        this.currentOperand = computation;
        this.operation = undefined;
        this.previousOperand = "";
    }

    updateDisplay() {
        this.currentOperandTextElement.innerText = this.currentOperand;
        if (this.operation != null) {
            this.previousOperandTextElement.innerText =
            `${this.previousOperand} ${this.operation}`
        } else {
            this.previousOperandTextElement.innerText = "";
        }

    }
}


const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-number]");
const operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-operation]");
const equalsButton = document.querySelector("[data-equals]");
const deleteButton = document.querySelector("[data-delete]");
const allClearButton = document.querySelector("[data-clear]");
const previousOperandTextElement = document.querySelector("[data-previous-operand]");
const currentOperandTextElement = document.querySelector("[data-current-operand]");

const calculator = new Calculator(previousOperandTextElement,
    currentOperandTextElement);

allClearButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    calculator.clear();
    calculator.updateDisplay();
})

numberButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {

        if(calculator.previousOperand === "" &&
        calculator.currentOperand !== "" &&
    calculator.readyToReset) {
            calculator.currentOperand = "";
            calculator.readyToReset = false;
        }
        calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText)
        calculator.updateDisplay();
    })
})

operationButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        calculator.chooseOperation(button.innerText)
        calculator.updateDisplay();
    })
})

equalsButton.addEventListener("click", button => {
    calculator.compute();
    calculator.updateDisplay();
})

deleteButton.addEventListener("click", button => {
    calculator.delete();
    calculator.updateDisplay();
})
```

```css
.calculator-grid{
   display: grid;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   min-height: 100;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 80px);
}

.calculator-grid > button {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 2em;
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    outline: none;
    background-color: rgb(233, 129, 129);
    margin: 1px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.output {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    background-color: rgb(251, 251, 251);
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100px;
}

#kalkulacka{
 width: 360px;
 height: 520px;
 background-color: rgb(0, 255, 221);
 margin: auto;
 top: 20px;
 position: center;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

.span-two{
    grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="kalkulacka" class="calculator-grid">
        <div class="output">
            <div data-history class="history">22</div>
            <div data-previous-operand class="previous-operand">22</div>
            <div data-current-operand class="current-operand">22</div>
        </div>
        <button data-clear>AC</button>
        <button data-delete>DEL</button>
        <button data-converse>+/-</button>
        <button data-operation>÷</button>
        <button data-number>7</button>
        <button data-number>8</button>
        <button data-number>9</button>
        <button data-operation>*</button>
        <button data-number>4</button>
        <button data-number>5</button>
        <button data-number>6</button>
        <button data-operation>-</button>
        <button data-number>1</button>
        <button data-number>2</button>
        <button data-number>3</button>
        <button data-operation>+</button>
        <button data-number>.</button>
        <button data-number>0</button>
        <button data-equals class="span-two">=</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: how do you set `this.operation`? I suggest you post the full code.

Comment: The code doesn't even run. I think you're missing `function` at the very beginning.

Comment: Can I send you a link to codepen? I´m new here and cant find how to eddit a this snippet.

Comment: Just click the 'edit' link underneath the tags. I've made that first edit for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this does what you want.

In your constructor, add:

```
   this.lastEntryWasOperation = false;
```

The at the beginning of `appendNumber()`, add:

```
   this.lastEntryWasOperation = false;
```

Then change `chooseOperation()` to:

```
if (this.lastEntryWasOperation)
    this.operation = operation;
else{
    if (this.currentOperand === "") return
    if (this.currentOperand !== "" && this.previousOperand !== "") this.compute();
    this.operation = operation;
    this.previousOperand = this.currentOperand;
    this.currentOperand = "";
}

this.lastEntryWasOperation = true;
```

Thus we keep track of whether the last key pressed was an operator, setting the flag to true if it was an operator, false if not.

Then if a second operator comes in immediately after another operator, we simply overwrite it rather than moving the operands around.

Comment: Is there a need to add `lastEntryWasOperation` if we can just check wether `this.operation` is defined ( other than for readability/debugging )

Comment: I´ll try that after I get home and then let you now. And thank you for helping me and not disliking this post to an oblivion.

Comment: Swimmer F. Jasper Kents code work. But I´m learning and I´m interested in your idea. What did you mean that i should do with the operation? Please post a snippet if you can so I can see my fauls clearly. Thank you.